Add a custom menu in context menu say "Consume" in sharepoint online list library
I am provisioning a "list view" and "document library" in sharepoint online.
Now by default some menu appears in context menu on the items of the list. I want to add the new menu in the same context menu and upon clicking the menu, it should open a another spfx page for some input. How to achieve it?
Have seen some example but i don't want to use java script. I want to add this logic in my SPFx solution and upon deploying the list should get created with these menu in context menu.
